# Facebook Api Permissions .Net

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

```
string OAuthURL = @"http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=app_id
                            &redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
                            &redirect_type=token
                            &scope=publish_actions,user_photos";

dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
                        {
                            client_id = "app_id",
                            client_secret = "app_secret",
                            redirect_uri = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
                            code = code,
                            scope = "publish_actions,user_photos"
                        });
```

I've tried both piece of code above but I cannot give permission for accounts. This causes some error like posting something. Also, when I get my permissions with fb.Get("/me/permissions"), none of permissions I wrote with scope is there.
I mean publish_stream or user_photos permissions cannot be seen there. Because of this, I get an error

> (OAuthException-#200)(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action.

What can I do to give permissions to my app or how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the accestoken like this

```
if (code == "" || code == null)
{
       //request for authentication
       Response.Redirect("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5176/");
}
else
{                
       fb = new MyFB();
       fb.ApplicationSecret = appSecret;
       fb.ApplicationID = appId;
       string accessToken = fb.GetAccessToken(code);
       fb.AccessToken = accessToken;              

       ViewData["MyName"] = fb.GetMyName();                
}
```

I advice you to use this tutorial as a future reference: http://codesamplez.com/facebook-c-sharp-api-tutorials

Comment: Actually, I can get access token, there is no problem with that. I design a form application and when I tried to click post button, I get the error. Main problem is permissions. Since I cannot give necessary permissions, I cannot post. Edit: I realize that access tokens that I get from my program and graph api explorer are different. I guess this causes the problem. Why could it happen?

Comment: They are different because an accestoken is usually unique. You do have to check if your permissions in your app are correct, not only in your C# code. Because the error you get tells you that your accestoken is incorrect, either because you don't get the correct permission from the user, or you get the wrong kind of accesstoken. Still I think the tutorial can help as a reference.

Comment: Now, I create app from my facebook account and if I login with my account there is no problem, I can do whatever I want such as giving all permissions, posting, image upload etc. However, if I login with another account, I can do nothing. For example, I logged in with my brother's account. After I tried to post, it failed. I looked permissions and there is no permissions except default one. I tried to change permissions from graph api explorer but this was not affect anything.

Comment: Okay, than I also have another question, is your facebook app public? Can't you change permission in the app? I remember when I made my application that you also had to set some stuff in the application before being able to use it (this was 2 years ago).

Comment: My app is public. After you asked it, I checked it again and it's public. I can change permissions in the app but it only affects my account's permission. I want to do it for every account that log in via my app.

Answer (score 0):

you must have to approve permission from facebook graph api explorer. For that you must go to

**Graph API Explorer -> Select your Application -> Get Acess Token .**

There will be list of permissions , you just need to check which permissions you want. afterward you can approve your token from C# code.

Comment: I did what you said. Although publish_actions and user_photos permissions are available, in my program they cannot be seen. Also, I want to login different accounts and I cannot do what you said with all accounts. I want to do that with my code. Edit: I realize that access tokens that I get from my program and graph api explorer are different. I guess this causes the problem. Why could it happen?